# How to eager fetch a child collection while joining child collection entities to an association

Tags: nhibernate, hql, icriteria, eager-loading

Assuming the following fictional layout

```
Dealership
  has many Cars
     has a Manufacturer
```

I want to write a query that says get me a Dealership with a Name of X and also get the Cars collection but use a join against the manufacturer when you do so.  I think this would require usage of ICriteria.  I'm thinking something like this..

```
var dealershipQuery = Session.CreateCriteria< Dealership>("d")
                             .Add(Restrictions.InsenstiveLike("d.Name", "Foo"))
                             .CreateAlias("d.Cars", "c")
                             .SetFetchMode("d.Cars", FetchMode.Select)
                             .SetFetchMode("c.Manufacturer", FetchMode.Join)
                             .UniqueResult< Dealership>();
```

But the resulting query looks nothing like I would have expected.  I'm starting to think a DetachedCriteria may be required somewhere but I'm not sure.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetching collections in the same query is almost never the best solution.

One of the best approaches is detailed in this link: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/16/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate.aspx

Personally, my preferred solution is to use `batch-size` in both the collections and the entities, set to the size of my default page length. That way, your query above would be done with 3 cheap, individually cacheable queries, instead of an expensive one.

Comment: I should have mentioned we're using an older Oracle so batch-size doesn't work.

Comment: Also I'm not trying to get two collections from Dealership.  I want Cars to load its Manufacturer eagerly.  The link you sent is more associated with multiple collections off a single root.

Comment: `batch-size` on entities and collections works on all databases. And Ayende's solution works for any number of collections; the idea is that you get the root(s) in one query and the collections in another.

Comment: Actually batch-size does not work on Oracle 9i.  It was only added to the 10+ client.

Comment: Accepting as an answer since you are correct.. if you have batch-size available it is the correct way to do things..  I guess I should see about getting our clients upgraded.